# Popup menu with Material Design 2

Tags: android, kotlin, popup, styles, material-design

I have a Popup menu that I create like this:

```
val popup = PopupMenu(this, more_button) 
popup.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_options, popup.menu) 
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this) 
popup.show()
```

But I can't seem to find how to create a Popup with that round corners edges like the new Google Chrome have for the "more button" on the right upper corner.

How do I create a Popup menu based on the new Material Design 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

With the new `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03` and `Theme.MaterialComponents` theme, all `PopupMenu` will have Mateiral Design2 look. When `material-1.1.0` is out, we'll have them all.

## Old Answer

> How do I create a Popup menu based on the new Material Design 2?

There is a third-party library [MaterialPopupMenu](https://github.com/zawadz88/MaterialPopupMenu).

Google has planned to create all material components but it seems that takes a long time.

BTW, Google Chrome creates the popup menu manually. The round corner is simply a .9.png file.
[code](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/appmenu/AppMenu.java#L204) and [popup_bg](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/chrome/android/java/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/popup_bg.9.png)